# Passport validity rule to enter Canada for tour

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, canada, turkish-airlines

My passport is expiring on 1 May 2018 and I am travelling to Canada in Oct 2017. My return journey date is 4 Nov 2017.  Will there be any problem during check-in / immigration / boarding as my passport won't be having a minimum 6 months validity during the return journey.

Comment: You can look this up online, but we need to know which nation's passport you are holding, as the answer depends on this. The fact that you travel on Turkish Airlines is however not important. Also, if you are entering on a specific visa type, this may also be of relevance.

Comment: A few years ago my wife entered Canada with a passport valid for one day after the return date. There was no problem.

Comment: @ugoren But, again, this may depend on the country that issued the passport.

Answer (score 4):

For a certain answer, your nationality must be considered. However, it seems like the 6-month rule isn't valid for Canada, and your passport is good enough.

Still, it would be a good idea to renew it, just in case (rules change, plans change, who knows).

Also note that an [eTA](https://canada-etavisa.info/) may be required. The eTA form requires that you fill in the passport expiry date. If it accpets your passport, it's a good indication that you're OK.

Sources:

- The [Canadian Border Services Agency web site](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html) states that a valid passport is required. No requirement for 6 months is mentioned.
- [lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/these-countries-follow-the-six-month-rule-for-passpor-1782577451) lists countries that require 6 months, with canada off the list.
- Timatc search on the [United Airlines site](https://www.united.com/web/en-us/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) returns - `Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for the period of intended stay.`
- Personal experience - I (accidentally) tested it in 2011, arriving by air with a passport expiring exactly one day after my return flight (one month after my arrival). I was allowed in with no problem.

Comment: @user62589, please update the question with this information.